# Modules installed in venv are not recognized

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

why it does not work? Django.tar.gz is straight from PyPi
if i try "python -m pip install" it works, but installs python globally.

```
(newenv) [root]# pip install paczki/Django-2.0.7.tar.gz
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Processing ./paczki/Django-2.0.7.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in ./newenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Django==2.0.7)
Installing collected packages: Django
  Running setup.py install for Django ... done
Successfully installed Django-2.0.7
(newenv) [root]# python3
Python 3.6.0 (default, May 22 2018, 12:59:04)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
>>>
```

Comment: Are you sure `python3` here refers to the same Python version as used by the virtualenv?  You didn't perhaps create an alias named `python3` by any chance, did you?

Comment: i think so.  running "python" and then "import django" gives the same result. Shouldnt it refer to pyton inside venv?

Comment: Ok, you are leading me to a good solution. Actually running pip with python3.6, and then running python3.6 gives good results. What is wrong? I inherited this VM to port my django app here, so i have no knowledge what last owner did to python instalation here.

Comment: (while in the venv directory) `which python`, `which python3` and `which python3.6` might provide helpful results

Comment: Ok, actually python3 and python lead do newenv/bin/python3, and python3.6 leads to global usr/local/bin. So still, django works only when installed with global python (python3.6), and fails to work when using venv python.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. There was an systemwide alias set earlier by someone, which aliased python to a specific path like "/A/B/python", thus even while in venv used python was this one. :which python: might be misleading - id DOES NOT check for aliases, so :which python: and :python: did not pointed to the same one.